# Tensor product of two vector space implies one of them zero?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, tensor-products

I found it on page 31 of Atiyah's *Commutative Algebra*. It says:

> If $M_k$, $N_k$ are vector spaces over a field, then $M_k \otimes N_k = 0$ implies $M_k=0$ or $N_k=0$.

Where $A$ is a local ring, $k$ is the residue field $A/\frak m$, $M,N$ are two $A$-modules, $M_k=k\otimes M,N_k=k\otimes N$.

I did not learn much linear algebra, and Atiyah did not give any further explanation.. So I'm stuck here until I found this: [Tensor product of two vector spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/276561/tensor-product-of-two-vector-spaces) .

It seems to solve my problem, but I'm starting to have more questions about ternsor product:

1. What is tensor product? I just know it is a multi-linear mapping of some modules, is there any geometric explanation?
2. In linear algebra, i.e., module over field, how to understand tensor product? and the example above ($M_k \otimes N_k = 0 \implies M_k=0$ or $N_k=0$)?

Comment: Your questions needs more focus. If you want to know what a tensor product is, read the definition, e.g., in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product).

Comment: @DietrichBurde I know what the definition is, but I want a geometric view. I know in differential geometry, they use tensor to describe something, so I hope someone can give a different view about it, not just the definition.

Comment: For the geometric intuition see for example [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/115630/geometric-intuition-of-tensor-product) and many other posts here.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thank you for your comment! I found this https://math.stackexchange.com/a/126936/1048243 in the link you just gave. Does that mean I can imagine the tensor as equivalence of a kind  of 'area'?